# Just how safe is protecting a page with session_start()?

Tags: php, security

After my login page all my other pages are inaccessible unless you are logged in. And basically to check if you are logged in I have a simple if else statement:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Show the page
} else {
    // Ask the user to log in
}
```

And for the admin pages I have an extra check:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['isAdmin'] == TRUE){
  // Show the page
} else {
  // Unauthorised access
}
```

Is this a safe way of protecting PHP pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is the safe way. and try to add `<?php if(!session_id()) session_start(); ?>` at the top of the page because if you have included this page in another page and session is already started in that page, the session will be canceled and this page will be prone to unauthorized users.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.
All PHP session variables are stored on the server side. The moment a session is started by `session_start();`. PHP sets a temporary cookie on your computer named `PHPSESSID` set to expire at the end of the browsing session. Using this cookie PHP server assigns values to the session variables. Whenever you log out (i.e, `session_destroy();`), this PHPSESSID cookie value is made useless

The insecure bit about this is if someone actually stole your `PHPSESSID` cookie value, the person can simply set this `PHPSESSID` cookie on their computer and have access to your session without even entering any username or password. However this can be mitigated if you use SSL/HTTPS on your web server. It must be enforced wherever `session_start();` is used. You must force SSL/HTTPS  where sessions are used.  If you just use SSL/HTTPS for login, and HTTP for the rest of the session, this doesn't make you safe as the `PHPSESSID` cookie is sent in plaintext via HTTP.

As far as I know the only way to compromise PHP's Session mechanism is to steal the `PHPSESSID` cookie using man-in-the-middle attacks, which can be totally made useless if you have a valid SSL certificate and use of strong cipher suite for your webserver. This cookie can also be retrieved using properly crafted XSS attacks, which can be mitigated if you filter javascript or equivalent from the PHP input to your PHP code using `preg_replace` with the proper regex.

Comment: Fantastic, we will definitely be purchasing an SSL certificate. Thanks for the in-depth information there is a lot I would like to look into that you have mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

**create one function then call this function when you load your page.. this function return true and false if you login or not and then you can manage your URL redirection..**

> > > oR

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
```

this lucks good..

Comment: both are correct but in my point of view the 1st solution provide better  among two ... :)